# Expect send KEY_DOWN and KEY_UP events to Process in Linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, expect, simulate, pexpect

I want to simulate embedded linux keypress events to my Qt GUI Application. Primarily I want to simulate KEY_UP, KEY_DOWN, KEY_LEFT, KEY_RIGHT, and KEY_F{1-2-3} key presses. I don't have X available.

There is an ASCII character table here:

```
http://foldoc.org/ASCII+character+table\
```

And I understand how to send things, say CNTRL-T, using that table to my aplication by spawning it and sending it the following in my expect script:

```
send "\x14"
```

I can't seem to find documentation or examples on how to send the KEY_??? key presses using Expect. How can I do this using Expect?

If not possible, is there some other way to send keypresses to my process? I can't seem to be able to echo escape sequences to /dev/input/keypad...

Update:

Thanks for the comments.

I can see the output that my arrow keys generate by doing:

```
$ od -c
^[[D^[[C^[[D^[[B^[[A^[[A^[[B^[[B^C
```

I can also see the output of **infocmp xterm** as:

```
am, bce, km, mc5i, mir, msgr, npc, xenl,
    colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64,
    acsc=``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
    bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,
    clear=\E[H\E[2J, cnorm=\E[?12l\E[?25h, cr=^M,
    csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H,
    cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=^J, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
    cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
    cvvis=\E[?12;25h, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM,
    dl1=\E[M, ech=\E[%p1%dX, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, el1=\E[1K,
    flash=\E[?5h$<100/>\E[?5l, home=\E[H, hpa=\E[%i%p1%dG,
    ht=^I, hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@, il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L,
    ind=^J, indn=\E[%p1%dS, invis=\E[8m,
    is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, kDC=\E[3;2~, kEND=\E[1;2F,
    kHOM=\E[1;2H, kIC=\E[2;2~, kLFT=\E[1;2D, kNXT=\E[6;2~,
    kPRV=\E[5;2~, kRIT=\E[1;2C, kb2=\EOE, kbs=\177, kcbt=\E[Z,
    kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,
    kdch1=\E[3~, kend=\EOF, kent=\EOM, kf1=\EOP, kf10=\E[21~,
    kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~, kf13=\EO2P, kf14=\EO2Q,
    kf15=\EO2R, kf16=\EO2S, kf17=\E[15;2~, kf18=\E[17;2~,
    kf19=\E[18;2~, kf2=\EOQ, kf20=\E[19;2~, kf21=\E[20;2~,
    kf22=\E[21;2~, kf23=\E[23;2~, kf24=\E[24;2~, kf25=\EO5P,
    kf26=\EO5Q, kf27=\EO5R, kf28=\EO5S, kf29=\E[15;5~,
    kf3=\EOR, kf30=\E[17;5~, kf31=\E[18;5~, kf32=\E[19;5~,
    kf33=\E[20;5~, kf34=\E[21;5~, kf35=\E[23;5~,
    kf36=\E[24;5~, kf37=\EO6P, kf38=\EO6Q, kf39=\EO6R,
    kf4=\EOS, kf40=\EO6S, kf41=\E[15;6~, kf42=\E[17;6~,
    kf43=\E[18;6~, kf44=\E[19;6~, kf45=\E[20;6~,
    kf46=\E[21;6~, kf47=\E[23;6~, kf48=\E[24;6~, kf49=\EO3P,
    kf5=\E[15~, kf50=\EO3Q, kf51=\EO3R, kf52=\EO3S,
    kf53=\E[15;3~, kf54=\E[17;3~, kf55=\E[18;3~,
    kf56=\E[19;3~, kf57=\E[20;3~, kf58=\E[21;3~,
    kf59=\E[23;3~, kf6=\E[17~, kf60=\E[24;3~, kf61=\EO4P,
    kf62=\EO4Q, kf63=\EO4R, kf7=\E[18~, kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~,
    khome=\EOH, kich1=\E[2~, kmous=\E[M, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~,
    mc0=\E[i, mc4=\E[4i, mc5=\E[5i, meml=\El, memu=\Em,
    op=\E[39;49m, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM, rin=\E[%p1%dT,
    rmacs=\E(B, rmam=\E[?7l, rmcup=\E[?1049l, rmir=\E[4l,
    rmkx=\E[?1l\E>, rmso=\E[27m, rmul=\E[24m, rs1=\Ec,
    rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, sc=\E7, setab=\E[4%p1%dm,
    setaf=\E[3%p1%dm,
    setb=\E[4%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,
    setf=\E[3%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,
    sgr=\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p7%t;8%;m%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;,
    sgr0=\E[m\E(B, smacs=\E(0, smam=\E[?7h, smcup=\E[?1049h,
    smir=\E[4h, smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smso=\E[7m, smul=\E[4m,
    tbc=\E[3g, u6=\E[%i%d;%dR, u7=\E[6n, u8=\E[?1;2c, u9=\E[c,
    vpa=\E[%i%p1%dd,
```

I've tried several of the simple escape sequences on a 'menuconfig' ( much like Linux ) program for Buildroot like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

# Span menuconfig
spawn make menuconfig

expect *
send {"\e[D"}
#send {"\e[%p1%dB"}

interact
```

I'd like to have the menuconfig open and the cursor move down one spot. However, it just launches and quits right away, even though I have an 'interact' statement in there. Any ideas as to why? Thanks -

Comment: What is the terminal type? `man 1 tput` will probably get you somewhere.

Comment: when I SSH to the embedded board, # echo $TERM, gives 'xterm'.

Comment: Than you should seduce expect to emit the escape codes that the xterm *expect*s for CUP, F1-F3, etc. Look them up in termcap/terminfo. Maybe expect knows about these (since the terminal is the raison d'etre for expect)

Comment: "my Qt GUI Application" .... "don't have X available" .... ? How does that work?

Comment: Ah, yes... missed the little "embedded" bit there...

Comment: `infocmp xterm` will give you the escape strings needed for xterm. You'll only need a few. Happy hacking!

Comment: IIRC, in `"\e[%p1%dB"`, the `%p1` refers to a parameter, probably numeric. Not sure about the "%d". long time ago... The Fine Manual is your friend. Happy hacking.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981982/pexpect-send-cursor-movement for a solution in pexpect. Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! This worked for moving the cursor. Feel free to answer below so I can accept an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using autoexpect ?
Try this :

```
$ autoexpect
```

And do what you want expect to do, if you would like it to scroll two lines down - send two down arrow events - do this by pressing down arrow twice.
Then exit autoexpect with Ctrl+C

Autoexpect will generate a script of all your actions that you can then run if you want expect to repeat the same thing. What is more important is that it will also catch the key events you want to send and generate correct lines of expect script that send these events. In my case (down arrow) this was

```
send -- "^[OB"
```

Just press all the keys you want to automatically send, and then inspect the generated script (usually named script.exp).
Hope this helps