# How to write an interactive bash to test a command

Tags: bash, shell

We have written a scaffold something similar to the vue-cli, we want to verify it through the pipeline.

we have a global command `rh-create`, once executed, it will create a project skeleton step by step.

I want to know how to write a bash to interact with this command?

I know `yes` command and `printf` command, and it seems cannot imitate the arrow up/down key.

Something I found through the internet related to `yes` and `printf`:

https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-interactive-prompts
[image]

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920320/expect-send-key-down-and-key-up-events-to-process-in-linux) discussion for sending terminal movement keystrokes to your application. Note that the escape sequences to be generated, also depend on the `TERM` variable.

Comment: If you read that article further, it also mentions expect, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a tool called `expect` instead of `bash`. It allows you to interact with a program as if you were a user. It depends on and works with the `tcl` package.

Comment: Expect is not part of Tcl.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells Pardon me; `expect` _depends on_ `tcl`.